# Windows Authentication For Single CD Page

Tags: authentication

I want to authenticate user based on there windows domain details, for **single Sitecore CD server Page**.
I Wanted to check if the user is accessing a page through my domain then allow user to login or redirect to 401. **I don't want to ask user to enter credentials again if he is from my domain**.

Comment: What version of Sitecore?

Comment: I am using Sitecore 9.3

Comment: To do active directory in 9.3, you are going to have to set up your identity server so it will connect to you AD via ADFS or another OAuth provider. Then the OAuth token and the identity token will keep the user logged in. https://sitecore.namics.com/2019/03/04/federated-authentication-in-sitecore-9-using-adfs-2016/ https://blog.istern.dk/2019/05/15/sitecore-9-1-identityserver-on-premise-ad-via-adfs/

Comment: IT will add windows authentication to entire site, but In my scenario I wanted to add windows authentication for Single public site(CD) page.
Also I don't want user to enter windows credentials again. If user is from my domain then I don't wan't to ask user to enter credentials again.

Comment: via the sites config file, you can pick what site gets authentication and which one doesn't. Identity server isn't easy, but it is the only way to configure AD auth for your site, in Sitecore.